# Regex pattern check is not working even after verifying the pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a password box that I am going to check against a Regex pattern. I have already got two other identical type of functions that work correctly on non password text boxes.

This is my function:

```
public bool CheckPassword(string password)
{
    string patternStrict = @"/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)\S{6,15}$/";
    Regex reStrict = new Regex(patternStrict);
    bool isStrictMatch = reStrict.IsMatch(password);
    return isStrictMatch;
}
```

and I am inputting a test to it like so:

```
Problem.Text = CheckPassword(passwordbox.Text);
```

The TextBox I am using (passwordbox) is filtered with * as the password character and that works but I am wondering if that is the cause for the function to fail?

I feel it is something obvious I have missed. The response should come back as true but it is coming back as false. See line 5 of the link supplied above as the test line to see if it works, that is the test line I am using to check if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET does not need a regex delimiter, so just remove the leading and the trailing slash:

```
string patternStrict = @"^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)\S{6,15}$";
```